# VB.NET dropdown list not populating with all items

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I am populating an asp dropdown list by reading data from a MySQL table via stored procedure.

The data reader returns all 4 rows from the table however only rows 2, 3, 4 are listed in the dropdown list.

This is the code that sets the dropdown list. Does anyone have any ideas on what may have gone wrong?

Thanks

```
 Try
        Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()

        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "Select_CatLibraryData"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Using catdata_rs As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If catdata_rs.Read() Then
                list_itemcategory.DataSource = catdata_rs
                list_itemcategory.DataValueField = "category"
                list_itemcategory.DataTextField = "category"
                list_itemcategory.DataBind()
            End If

        End Using

    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException

        lbl_ErrorPanelText.Text = "Error establishing a database connection!"
        pn_ErrorPanel.Visible = True

    End Try
```

Comment: use SqlDataAdapter with DataSet or DataTable, rather than Reader. I think it is better way

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `If catdata_rs.Read()` since it advances the pointer by 1.

Instead use code like below. Or you could just remove the surrounding `if` around databinding code and directly bind to data reader and if its empty then your list drop down will also be empty.

```
If catdata_rs.HasRows Then
            list_itemcategory.DataSource = catdata_rs
            list_itemcategory.DataValueField = "category"
            list_itemcategory.DataTextField = "category"
            list_itemcategory.DataBind()
End If
```